# How to convert localDate type object to jsonObject like gson by using jakson

Tags: java, json, gson, localdate

When I converted object to json Object by using Jakson library, the result json output is as follows.

```
"runDate":{"date":{"hour":11,"minute":5,"second":27,"nano":500000000,"monthValue":6,"year":2018,"dayOfMonth":8,"dayOfWeek":"FRIDAY","dayOfYear":159,"month":"JUNE","chronology":{"id":"ISO","calendarType":"iso8601"}}
```

but When I used library gson:

```
"runDate":{"date":{"month":6,"year":2018,"day":8},"time":{"hour":11,"nano":518000000,"minute":9,"second":21}}
```

**Problem: How to convert the object to jsonObject like gson by using jakson**

```
java set LocalDate,
log.setRunDate(LocalDateTime.now(z));
```

My pom jakson dependency version:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Can you help me how to convert the object to jsonObject like gson by using jakson

Comment: why would you want to do that in the first place? simply use the GSON its free , available and capable

Comment: Jackson has a + in performance and that's very important for me. especially when I work big file. Beside gson use code of jakson in baseline this jar useful for small file. and Jakson has a lot overriding method count more has alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a class which matching your json data,you can do it similar to Gson.

```
// json Object Mapper class
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

//convert json string to object
YourClass emp = objectMapper.readValue(jsonData, YourClass.class);
```